# __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given , an error about web crawler

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-crawler, selenium-chromedriver

Recently , I want to make a web crawler ,and I am newbie in programming. I know this error is common in stackoverflow.com ,but I studied and tried million times .It's still failed.
Below is my code , it's semi-finished.

```
import requests
import time

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver


from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait



chrome_path = "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Scripts\chromedriver.exe" 
web = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

web.get('https://www.agoda.com/zh-tw/pages/agoda/default/DestinationSearchResult.aspx?asq=%2bZePx52sg5H8gZw3pGCybdmU7lFjoXS%2baxz%2bUoF4%2bbAP7QU5sGtWmrzIvlWpeSVhG7hBqSW0J1d8hA8mgoocSdtpIj66gXToDH6PLoebpS2%2b7zRXCrzWTxWGJcCS2%2b98%2bkomkepA8A1QWe2FGYglfZpxj%2fA%2bylTfAGs1qJCjm9nxgYafyEWBFMPjt2sg351B&city=18343&tick=636125544363&isdym=true&searchterm=%E5%A2%BE%E4%B8%81&pagetypeid=1&origin=TW&cid=-1&htmlLanguage=zh-tw&checkIn=2016-10-25&checkOut=2016-10-26&los=1&rooms=1&adults=2&children=0&isFromSearchBox=true&ckuid=db61c7c8-1cf8-4b14-9c04-9c8aababbac5')


soup=BeautifulSoup(web.page_source,"lxml")

#wait=ui.WebDriverWait(web,10)

a=1

hotelname=web.find_elements_by_class_name("hotel-name")

try:    
    while len(soup.select('.btn-right')) >0:
        print("page",a)
        a=a+1

        for number,name in enumerate(hotelname):
            print(number,name.text.strip())
            #time.sleep(1)


        if len(soup.select('.btn-right'))>0 :
            web.find_element_by_id("paginationNext").click()
            soup=BeautifulSoup(web.page_source,"lxml")
            hotelname=web.find_elements_by_class_name("hotel-name")
        else:
            break

    web.close()
except:
    time.sleep(3)
    print("wake up")
    WebDriverWait(web,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH,"//button[@data-selenium='pagination-next-btn']"))
    web.find_element_by_id("paginationNext").click()
    print("click ok")
```

When I run this code , I get the error message:

**File "C:/Users/Elvis/.spyder-py3/driver2.py", line 77, in 
    WebDriverWait(web,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.CLASS_NAME,"pagination-next-btn"))
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given**

I guess that there is a bug in this line

```
WebDriverWait(web,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH,"//button[@data-selenium='pagination-next-btn']"))
```

I just want to check this button is clickable, or wait for 10 seconds.
I try to adjust the path and tag much times, but doesn't work.
By the way, I use python3 , win10 and chromedriver.
If you have idea ,please help me ,I really want solve this problem and finish my first web-crawler. 
Thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJkt5.png)

Answer (score 2):

You should give tuple of args to `element_to_be_clickable((locator type, locator))`, but not two separate args `element_to_be_clickable(locator type, locator)`

```
WebDriverWait(web,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@data-selenium='pagination-next-btn']")))
```

Comment: This must be about the most common error in Selenium code; unpacking the location tuple. I'm not sure why the project doesn't just accept two arguments as an alternative.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The python bindings are notoriously unpythonic and that is not going to change because of legacy reasons. Fortunately selenium is already obsolete when it comes to web-crawling. We have [splash](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash) and bunch of other similar, proper tools.

Comment: Oh it's amazing. It works great.Thank you.